# Casella and Berger, Statistical Inference, Problem 6.36

Tags: statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference

As stated in the book:

> **6.36** One advantage of using a minimal sufficient statistic is that unbiased estimators will have smaller variance, as the following exercise will show.  Suppose that $T_1$ is sufficient and $T_2$ is minimal sufficient, $U$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, and define $U_1=E(U|T_1)$ and $U_2=E(U|T_2)$.
>
> (a) Show that $U_2=E(U_1|T_2)$,
>
> (b) Now use the conditional variance formula (Theorem 4.4.7) to show that $\mathrm{Var}\,U_2\leq\mathrm{Var}\,U_1$.

Unsure of how to solve (a) I treated its result as a lemma and was able to use the law of total variance to establish the inequality in (b).

Back to part (a), I tried working backwards starting with

$$
E(U_1|T_2)=E(E(U|T_1)|T_2)=?=E(U|T_2)=U_2.
$$

The step given by (?) probably is where I need to use the minimal sufficiency of $T_2$ but I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: When doing repeated conditioning, the smallest sigma algebra always wins. In formulae, if $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal G$, then $$E(E(X\mid \mathcal G)\mid\mathcal F))=E(E(X\mid \mathcal F)\mid \mathcal G)) = E(X\mid \mathcal F)$$ Since $T_2$ is minimal sufficient, the claim follows

Comment: @Andrew I don't believe this book introduces the concept of $\sigma$-algebras so I am looking for an answer that does not involve them.

Comment: Then how does the book define conditional expectation? If it defines it using conditional densities, there seems to be some assumptions  missing from the question. If it defined it using orthogonal projection, then it should be simple to establish such a property as well.

Comment: @Andrew It defines it with conditional densities. Your (edited) first comment does make sense but the why in the first equality is where I'm lacking.